# Stacked graph not showing on chart. R ggplot geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-visualization, geom-area

I am trying to show a stacked graph using an area chart. However, after i input the variables for x and y and the fill data, nothing shows on the graph.

```
ggplot()+
geom_area(data=provinces,aes(x=variable,y=value,fill=Province.State))
```

```
Province.State variable value
         Hubei 01.22.20   444
     Guangdong 01.22.20    26
         Henan 01.22.20     5
      Zhejiang 01.22.20    10
         Hunan 01.22.20     4
         Anhui 01.22.20     1
         Macau 01.27.20     6
         Tibet 01.27.20     0
         Hubei 01.28.20  3554
     Guangdong 01.28.20   207
         Henan 01.28.20   168
      Zhejiang 01.28.20   173
         Hunan 01.28.20   143
         Anhui 01.28.20   106
       Jiangxi 01.28.20   109
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j6kH.png)

Comment: You have backtick-quoted the `geom_area()` bit which seems wrong to me. Also, please don't post data [as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827).

Comment: Welcome lams, an example that we can reproduce would help, the reprex package is great for that, and so is this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added sample data, i am not sure exactly why nothing is showing on the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`variable` is not continuous; without transforming those strings into something numeric, it's a factor with three discrete values. Either use `geom_bar(stat='identity')`, to keep `variable` as a factor, or parse the dates:

```
ggplot(provinces,
  aes(x=as.Date(variable, format='%m.%d.%y'),
  y=value,
  fill=Province.State)) + geom_area()
```

(After parsing the data with:

```
provinces <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='Province.State variable value
         Hubei 01.22.20   444
     Guangdong 01.22.20    26
         Henan 01.22.20     5
      Zhejiang 01.22.20    10
         Hunan 01.22.20     4
         Anhui 01.22.20     1
         Macau 01.27.20     6
         Tibet 01.27.20     0
         Hubei 01.28.20  3554
     Guangdong 01.28.20   207
         Henan 01.28.20   168
      Zhejiang 01.28.20   173
         Hunan 01.28.20   143
         Anhui 01.28.20   106
       Jiangxi 01.28.20   109
')
```

.)